# Problemas com excessos de requisições de pesquisa no google

Tags: python, google, python-requests

Durante o desenvolvimento de um projeto em Python que necessita realizar diversas buscas automatizadas no Google. Em algum momento, como já esperado, o Google bloqueia as requisições declarando "atividade suspeita".

Minha pergunta é:
Existe alguma maneira de evitar esse impasse? Ou, é possível continuar realizando essas buscas definindo um intervalo de tempo maior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Google é notoriamente difícil de crawlear e emprega diversas medidas anti-bot. [Aqui](https://blog.hyperiongray.com/6-golden-rules-google-scraping/) tem algumas dicas que ajudam um pouco, mas ainda assim a cadência máxima é bem pequena.

O que sugiro é usar a [API do Bing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/bing-web-search-api/), que é um jeito oficial de obter resultados de buscas e vai facilitar seu trabalho razoavelmente.

Comment: Estou utilizando API do Bing.
Muito obrigado Pedro, isso é para um projeto de pesquisa aqui na Universidade. Você será referenciado.